# Navigate tagged questions with "Next" button

Tags: feature-request, tags, review-queues

I most frequently look for questions by tag, sorted by newest or active and work down the list, looking for something interesting and worth answering. Most of the time, I just vote, maybe comment or edit and move on.

I'm effectively reviewing posts by tag.

It would speed up this reviewing process if there was a <kbd>Next</kbd> button available when users have navigated to a question via a tag (as opposed to a search result).

Possibly here:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The kind of users that navigate by tag, are usually people that are looking to review or answer questions in a specific tag, so I feel it would benefit a bunch of users.

At present, I usually navigate backwards to the list and then into the next question.

The first issue is going back and forth, and secondly when I'm quickly switching between questions, remembering which question to go to next isn't that clear with the lack of visual clarity between visited links an non-visited links.

Comment: I could see this being useful in _specific_ tags (e.g.: `vba-word`, `tsql`), but not much for more generic tags (e.g.: `html`, `sql-server`) in which two consecutive questions could be completely unrelated

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro one of the main tags I would use it for is [sql-server] and I would definitely find it useful.

Comment: @Tanner i agree with the suggested feature request its too repetitive to go back and open the next question kind request to SO please implement it

Answer (score 1):

**This sounds like something better done with a user script**. You would need to keep some references, like what the "next" and "previous" questions were, but you could also get that from the tag pages which you were just on.

**I don't think it would be useful in the grand scheme of things** (for the large majority of users) as most people aren't flipping through questions in the same tag/search results for a long period of time. Most people are using the search and only checking out a few questions before moving onto the next search.

It would also take up a bit of space in the side bar, a place which a lot of effort appears to have been put into making it clean. On top of that, making two floating buttons (which only appear *sometimes*) fit into the UI would be one of the biggest issues.

User scripts have their place, and this is one of them.

Comment: In the tags I'm active in, I notice users that I see over and over again, people that specialize in a specific technology. These users actively answer, comment on and edit posts. I assume these users do as I do, and navigate to posts via favorite tags, and they might find this useful. Again, I assume the same is true for other tags. I can understand not cluttering up the side bar, but I'm sure there'd be room somewhere for a button if it was deemed useful.