# Provide a way to disable the new Next / Previous question buttons

Tags: feature-request, design, navigation-arrows

Since recently, there have been two new buttons at either side of new questions. I find them quite distracting, as they are fixed in place, and stay in place as you scroll. Also, they pop up *after* the page loads, which is similarly distracting.

> [image: Screenshot]

I don't think they are terribly useful, as clicking will take me to some question which I probably *don't* want to see.

Could an option be added to disable these ?

Or  make them less intrusive, such as a link below the question (maybe under the asker info box, similar to the "add comment" link or in the sidebar, and perhaps also show the title of the next / previous item) ?

Comment: No repro.  What is your machine's specs?  Do you have any plugins that might cause this?

Comment: @Makoto, Maybe it's a staged rollout or testing on a few users. I'm on Firefox 35, Linux, they don't show in Chrome.

Comment: I'm more inclined to blame Firefox than believe it's a staged rollout at this point.  What do you see when you inspect those elements?

Comment: I see the buttons as well, definitely a Stack Exchange product. I like them a lot, though. Seem very useful for working through a list of questions.

Comment: @Makoto - You have to open the question from a list (like from the main page or a tag) to get the arrows to navigate through the list.

Comment: @Pekka웃, Yes, If you're working through a list of questions it's useful. Would still be nice if they were a little smaller / less intrusive.

Comment: Related: [Big arrow navigation confusing for home page lists](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294440/2675154).

Comment: Where were these buttons introduced in [meta]? I've only just noticed them.

Comment: It's A/B testing. We're seeing if they drive more answers or not.  Pseudo-secret pro-tip:  If you have keyboard shortcuts enabled, you can use j/k to go back or forward without the tyranny of your mouse/trackpad.

Comment: @Jaydles You should make the tags that the arrows can browse through configurable.

Comment: @JasonC, They are already pretty smart at what tags to show you. For example, if you come from the [jsoup] newest questions list, the buttons will only show you [jsoup] questions, even if they are tagged [java] also.

Comment: @JasonC they browse the source list you came from, so once you're on the tag page you want and click a question, they'll only show questions with that tag.

Comment: Question is only tagged as discussion. Should'nt it be a feature-request ?

Comment: It seems I'm also in the test group. I can see how these would be useful to some styles of answering, but they're entirely superfluous to me (I prefer to skim the titles in the list rather than go through all one-by-one), so I'd agree that making them optional would be appreciated. If nothing else though, it would be nice if the tooltip text gave me the question snippet, like the main page does. I think the reason they feel jarring is because they are so separate from the page. It would be nicer if they tried to fit-in (perhaps as a <> to the right of the question title?)

Comment: @Dave, I agree about showing a tooltip with the question title and the first few lines of the question. Maybe the buttons could be put in the sidebar, perhaps under the view counts / active stats.

Comment: This will be an option that I can turn off, right?

Comment: I hate the buttons, they make the site feel rather generic.

Comment: @Jaydles Doesn't the j/k keyboard shortcut conflict with [existing ones](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-keyboard-shortcuts/)?

Comment: @DavidG, I don't think so - they should be the same function: "Show me the next/previous question, based on the list from which I arrived on this question."

Comment: @Jaydles Are you sure? I've just tested on a non-SO site and j/k cycles between posts on a single question. So j will jump to the question, press again and it jumps to the first answer and so on.

Comment: @DavidG, well, I'm a LOT less sure *now*. :)  Thanks, we'll take a look.

Comment: FYI, it is hard for me to articulate the *visceral* negative reaction I had to seeing those buttons. It literally made me want to leave the site immediately. Even if it turns out that a lot of people love it (really?) I **really** **REALLY** want this to be something I can turn off.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285137/navigate-tagged-questions-with-next-button, @Jaydles has the feature been pulled or is it being tweaked, I'd quite like to see it.

Comment: I would personally welcome such buttons (maybe not as they have been implemented as seen [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294458), as obtrusive buttons to the side, but as a pair of arrows next to the question title maybe), as having to return to the newest questions list is quite unproductive (requiring an extra click) and infuriating.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using Adblock/Adblock Edge/uBlock, add the two following custom filters:

```
stackoverflow.com##.previous-button
stackoverflow.com##.next-button
```

Comment: Also works with uBlock.

Comment: @Oriol: Cheers for the info, added into post.

Comment: If you're going to do it yourself on the client, you can do it with [stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=fr) also.

Comment: @KyleMit: I'll take your word for it, I'm not a Chrome user.

Answer (score 6):

Fellow test subject here.

I wrote this userscript to get rid of it. Sort of. It's not perfect (flicker) but...

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        remove-nav-buttons
// @namespace   phenix
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include     http://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==


window.addEventListener('load', function() { 
  var previous = document.querySelector('.previous-button'), 
      next = document.querySelector('.next-button'); 

  if (previous) { 
    previous.parentNode.removeChild(previous); 
  }
  if (next) { 
    next.parentNode.removeChild(next); 
  }
});
```

For those that were asking, here's the HTML:

```
<div class="previous-button">
    <a title="previous question" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269251/ajax-requests-not-working-parallel?listId=a6f04c1cbeec43bc91205c897fcec20e" class="hit-box">
        <div class="left-arrow"></div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="next-button">
    <a title="next question" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269923/providing-input-to-another-program-using-console-application?listId=a6f04c1cbeec43bc91205c897fcec20e" class="hit-box">
        <div class="right-arrow"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Edit:

In Firefox, the first response back from the server has this nugget in it (formatting mine):

```
<script>
StackExchange.ready(function() { 
    StackExchange.question.initNextPreviousButtons({
        "IsFromNextPrevious":true,
        "QuestionId":30270013,"ExpectedListId":"8b2543c85c0d47e2b050ef79ca54739f",
        "Referrer":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269959/flot-how-to-show-the-x-axis-values-instead-of-y-axis-when-however"
    }); 
});
</script>
```

In which the response to Chrome is missing this. It seems based on comments above that the browser isn't indicative of whether or not this will load.

Comment: I might be able to make a user stylesheet to hide them without flicker. Thanks anyway !

Comment: If you wanted to do this with JS instead of CSS, seems like it'd be easier to just override `StackExchange.question.initNextPreviousButtons` with an empty function.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I actually had tried that once I found that function but couldn't get the loading order right. I spent 2 minutes on this anyhow so...