# The Previous/Next question buttons should skip ignored tags

Tags: discussion, questions

The new Previous/Next question buttons which have appeared over the weekend are a great feature, but they don't skip ignored tags.

I answer questions primarily under the HTML CSS and JavaScript tags, but due to the vast amount of applications of these three tags there are a lot of related tags I have ignored. Two examples of these are JavaScript plugins I've never used and CSS implementations which aren't related to websites.

One tag I have *ignored* is [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs). I've only barely ever touched on AngularJS development and do not have the expertise to answer the vast majority of questions this tag welcomes, so it's often pointless for me to visit them. However take this example:

[image: Example]

If I click into the *Jquery Horizontal Scrolling Timeline* question and click the *next question* button, I'll be taken to the *Content of absolute div not sizing down* question which features the ignored [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) tag. Here I'd be better off just hitting my browser's back button than clicking the next button.

Comment: where do i find these previous next buttons?

Comment: @Tanner if you get to a question from a list of questions (click on a question on the [main page](http://stackoverflow.com/), for instance), you'll see arrows to the left and right of the window. http://i.imgur.com/Mqdi4hj.png

Comment: don't see them on my machine (in chrome). sounds a bit like my proposal: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285137/navigate-tagged-questions-with-next-button

Comment: see them in firefox and IE (both of which i'm not logged in to)...

Comment: I'm using Chrome (Windows). They only appear if your browser window is large enough to fit them without covering other content.

Comment: My window is big enough to fit them on, plenty of whitespace, so not sure why they're not showing in Chrome.

Comment: @Tanner probably caching.

Comment: lol when all else fails.... caching :) fixed with a restart of browser.

Comment: Odd. I'm not seeing them either. (And yes, I have restarted my browser ;) )

Comment: Is this still implemented as I can't see it in any browser?!

Comment: @Tanner this does indeed appear to have been removed.

Comment: ah crap, I just forgot about it for a while then went to use it and couldn't find it. perhaps they tested it and weren't happy, will search for any related postings instead.

Comment: related post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294445/provide-a-way-to-disable-the-new-next-previous-question-buttons