# Ignore tag button in question body

Tags: feature-request, tags

The `Previous/Next question buttons` in the question body is a great feature

[image]

Since my ignore tag cloud is really huge, the possibility to add a tag in the ignore/favorite list in the question body can be really useful feature.
In this manner I can discover new interesting tag, then I can have a strong tool to clean my question list.
There is something I don't have considered about this possible feature?

Comment: I posted a similar topic earlier: [The Previous/Next question buttons should skip ignored tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294567/the-previous-next-question-buttons-should-skip-ignored-tags)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly already upvoted

Comment: where do i find the previous/next buttons?

Comment: @Tanner I have just updated my question with a screenshot

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285137/navigate-tagged-questions-with-next-button